# add new GPG key detailed in Docker installation

Tags: docker

completely new to 'Docker', wondered what this means in installation instructions.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

```
4/ Add the new GPG key.
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --   recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the [**SecureApt**](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt) (strong crypto to validate downloaded packages)

> apt-key is a program that is used to manage a keyring of gpg keys for secure apt.
> `gpg` is the tool used in secure apt to sign files and check their signatures

That works... if the key server is up (see [issue 13555](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13555), and "[Key server times out while installing docker on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/811540/5470)")

> The pool `hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net` is a subset of servers which are also available on port 80. It's more friendly to firewalls and companies.
>
> For some reason, most docker documentations and tutorials are giving that `p80` pool for installation, without further explanation.
>
> The thing is, this is a small pool of servers and they fail very often in practice. (The fact that most tutorials are sending people to that small pool probably doesn't help either).